# NuSOAP and content type

Tags: php, nusoap

Can't figure out how to make NuSOAP use UTF-8 for a content type. it keeps spitting out "ISO-8859-1". here's the relevant code bits that I've tried:

```
$soapclient=new soapclient($url1,'wsdl');
$soapclient->http_encoding='utf-8';
$soapclient->defencoding='utf-8';

if($soapclient->fault){
    $retdata=$soapclient->fault;
}else{
    if($soapclient->getError()){
        $retdata=$soapclient->getError();
    }else{
                    $params=array($xmldata);
                    $retdata=$soapclient->call($doit,$params,$url1,$url2);
    }
}
```

here's the request:

```
POST xxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.0
Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
SOAPAction: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
Content-Length: 1629
```

I've even gone into nusoap.php and changed a couple of lines that had the ISO hard-coded in. What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
$soapClient->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$soapClient->decode_utf8 = false;
```

Also make sure you're sending utf8 encoded data, otherwise it's a bit of a contradiction. (utf8_encode()).

Comment: well, that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: after working on this further, I'm still getting the same issue. I've added this: $xmldata=utf8_encode($xmldata); 

put this at the top of the script: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

set my php.ini: default_charset = "utf-8" 

and still it shows as 'charset=ISO-8859-1"! What next to do?

Comment: I spent hours and hours to find a solution. Thanks you're the man of the day.

Answer (score 1):

using [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/es/class.soapclient.php) works fine for me.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient(
                    "http://localhost/app/ws/index.php?ws=data&wsdl",
                    array('encoding'     => 'UTF-8',)
            );

$data = $client->__soapCall("data.getData", array(1));
?>
```

Tested with PHP 5.3.3.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$soapclient->defencoding='utf-8';
```

to

```
$soapclient->soap_defencoding='utf-8';
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems in NuSOAP, HTTP content type is being set in two files :

```
class.soap_server.php

nusoap.php
```

First find lines in each file :

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n");
```

and replace them with

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8\r\n");
```

It will solve your problem with HTTP headers. But I am not sure that this will solve any encoding problem since I have been struggling with UTF-8 encoding problem in NuSOAP it is not only because of HTTP Headers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing when I was faced with this problem (after a couple of days of pulling my hair out):

Went digging through the NuSOAP files and found the variable: `$soap_defencoding` which defaults to `ISO-8859-1`. However, on the line right below is a comment out version of the declaration that defaults to `UTF-8`.

There are two places that I found this: `nusoap_base.php` and `nusoap.php`. I found my problem went away when I had both changed over (inverse the commenting on the two lines).

Problem:  Client complains that the response encoding is `ISO-8859-1`
Solution: Change the following lines in the NuSOAP files `nusoap_base.php` and `nusoap.php`:

from:

`var $soap_defencoding = 'ISO-8859-1';`
`//var $soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';`

to:

`//var $soap_defencoding = 'ISO-8859-1';`
`var $soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';`

For reference my Client -> VB.NET 3.5 desktop application

Answer (score 0):

Double check the actual file is it is under utf-8 encoding. Sometimes the problem is the actual file and its encoding usually happens with Linux server.

Try changing the whole nusoap library and the controller and view files.

Change the file example ANSI to utf-8 or utf-8 without BOM.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
$client->setHTTPContentType('application/soap+xml');
```